# Friction acting on block

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

The frictional force acting on the block if it does not slide relative to the wedge which moves with an acceleration a towards right is

[image]

Friction $f$ and the component of pseudo force ($ma$) act up the incline and down the incline $mg\sin\theta$ Is acting, which gives $f+ma\cos\theta=mg\sin\theta$ which gives $f$ as $m(g\sin\theta-a\cos\theta)$, but the answer is given as $m(a\cos\theta-g\sin\theta)$.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ does not act **up** the incline but **down** the incline. The sign is opposite and then the whole thing fits.

Remember that the wedge is trying to move away from the block **towards the right**. The static friction force is trying to pull the box along with the wedge **towards the right** to make it follow.

Comment: How do we know that the component of pseudo force, in wedge frame, is greater than the component of weight of block along inclined plane?? It could also be that the acceleration of wedge is less enough to not overpower the component of weight of block along the incline plane, and so friction must act up the incline then..

Comment: I'm confused...